# When the derivative is equal to 1?

Tags: derivatives

Looking at reciprocal functions, they have 2 “turning” points, where the higher derivative values near vertical asymptotes turn into the generally lower ones approaching the end behavior asymptote, for example, taking $$y=\frac1x$$ the points are $(1,1)$ and $(-1,-1)$.   It appears that these points are where the derivative is equal to $1$ or $-1$.

Looking at exponential and logarithmic functions, they also have these points where the value of the derivatives begin to sharply decrease or increase.

I’m wondering whether these points have a specific name?

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for points of greatest [curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature)?

Comment: What, _exactly_, is your definition of "the higher derivative values near vertical asymptotes" and "the generally lower ones approaching the end behavior asymptote"? Those seem like very vague concepts to me.

Comment: For example,  y=1/x, the derivative is $-1/x^2$. In the domain (-1,0) and (0,1), the absolute value of the derivative is greater than one, but past those points, the absolute value of the derivative is always less than 1.